# Is it possible to use foreach to auto-increment from the value of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that sets a number for each animal. I want to create a loop which will auto-increment for however number of animals there are

```
$animal = array(
    'dog' => 2,
    'cat' => 4,

    );
foreach($animal as $pet => $num) {
    echo(sprintf('this is %s number $s', $pet, $num));
    };
```

Ideally I want it to display

this is dog number 1

this is dog number 2

this is cat number 1

this is cat number 2

this is cat number 3

this is cat number 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$animal = array(
'dog' => 2,
'cat' => 4,

);

foreach($animal as $pet => $num){
$i = 0;
while($num > 0)
{
    $i++;
    echo "This is $pet number $i<br/>";
    $num--;
}
}
```

Comment: No worries, there are other shorter blocks of code that would do essentially the same thing, but it's very easy for a person with any level of coding the see the logic behind how this is working. glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is any need of another nested for loop , try this

```
    $animal = array(
      'dog' => 2,
      'cat' => 4,
    );

    $i = 1;
    foreach($animal as $pet => $num) {
      echo "this is $pet number $i";
      $i++;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Probably not the most elegant solution but it works

```
$animal = array(
    'dog' => 2,
    'cat' => 4,

    );


foreach ($animal as $pet => $num):

    for ($i=1; $i <= $num; $i++):

        echo 'This is '.$pet.' number '.$i;

    endfor;

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$animal = array(
    'dog' => 2,
    'cat' => 4,

    );
foreach($animal as $pet => $num) {
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
echo "this is $pet number $i";
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something more like:

```
foreach($animal as $pet => $count){
    for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
        printf('this is %s number %d', $pet, $i);
    }
}
```